# Concept on displaying cross-table(conjunction) data in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Just a rookie in .NET MVC world and still learning

I created three EF models in framework, one is clients, one is order, and items, below is the relation:

```
Client          Order         Items
PK:ID          PK Order.id    PK Items.ID
...            FK:Client.id   ...
               FK:Item.id
```

In this case I wanna display all the client information and the item details they've bought in one table, obviously  I cannot use any DBcontext here. So what should I do to combine the three table's info and output that? Create a new model on those three?

Any ideas or article are very welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a ViewModel with all of the Data that you want to display.  This is the model that will get populated in the controller and then it would get passed to the View.

So in the View it would use the ViewModel and wouldn't need to know about the underlying Database Model.

And in the Controller you would get the data needed and populate the ViewModel and pass that model onto the View.

Here is a page with an examples.  There are plenty more out there too.  http://sampathloku.blogspot.com/2012/10/how-to-use-viewmodel-with-aspnet-mvc.html

Comment: Mn.. you mean write a class to pack all the page data? that's a good idea.
How about the cross request info? what you prefer to use?

Comment: I prefer using a class with the data needed.  Meaning a ClientInfoViewModel that would have ClientId, OrderId, ItemNames[] or something like that.  Just what is needed for the View to display correctly.  It will also help take logic out of the View